# simple scrolling in jQuery does not work

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, window-resize

Can anyone tell why the below piece of code does not work? It is intended to make screen scroll smoothly to destination of an anchor, respecting the height of the fixed header (here with ID "jeden").

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var headerHeight, part, place;

function getOffsets() {
    headerHeight = $('#jeden').height();
    part = $(this).attr('href');
    place = $(part).offset().top - headerHeight;
}

$(window).load(getOffsets).resize(getOffsets);

$(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: place
        }, 'slow');

        return false;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: try  -- scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('#jeden').height()

Answer (score 0):

In this function;:

```
function getOffsets() {
    headerHeight = $('#jeden').height();
    part = $(this).attr('href');
    place = $(part).offset().top - headerHeight;
}
```

There's no scope. `$(this)` would be returning an exception or `undefined`, so you need to define something there.

Comment: I changed it to   `part = $('div').attr('href');`   but it still does note work. Links just stopped leading anywhere.

Comment: Which `div` is it that you want the window to scroll to when you resize your window?

Comment: Well, I put `div`, because all parts of page which the links in header navigate to are `div`s with proper `id` corresponding to `href`.

Comment: which `href` do you want to use then? Which `div` contains that specific `href`? You can't use all `href`'s to scroll..

Comment: Ok, I get it. I thinkg it needs to be `href` of that particular link which was clicked.

Comment: Yes. And you need to save it somewhere to call back on resize.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will refactor it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help :) I managed to get a code working. I also limited the code only to the links in main navigation. I discovered that if I had not done it, other links I had in tab panel on my page, would have stopped working. So I gave a class `.anchorHeader` to the links in main navigation and I rebuilt the code in the following way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var headerHeight, part, place;

    function getOffsets() {
        headerHeight = $('#jeden').height(); 
    }

    $(window).load(getOffsets).resize(getOffsets);

    $(function () {
        $('.headerAnchor').click(function () {
            part = $(this).attr('href');
            place = $(part).offset().top - headerHeight;

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: place
            }, 'slow');

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

It works perfect also when resizing window - thanks to the suggestions I found in this forum: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/scrolling-when-resizing-window